# Is it possible to transfer USDC from Fantom Opera network to BEP-20 network?

Tags: network, binance-smart-chain, bridge, fantom

I have tried couple of bridging websites like Anyswap, Spookyswap but it failed badly. My coins are stuck in Fantom network. I want to switch them to other network, any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

This stack is meant for developers, that kind of question doesn't really belong here. To answer you though, bridges like anyswap should work, at least in my experinence they do. Another option is to go through a CEX, like binance. Deposit your USDC on Fantom to binance, and withdraw them to the BSC